# How to expand error in Django dev server?

Tags: django

I have trouble figuring out what trailing slash that causing an error in Django. This is the error:

> ?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '^/' has a regex beginning with a '/'.
>   Remove this slash as it is unnecessary.

My **urls.py** looks like this:

```
urlpatterns += [
    #url('^$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'index.html'}, name='home'),
    url('^$', mezzanine.blog.views.blog_post_list, name='home'),
    url('^', include('main.urls')),
    url('^', include('mezzanine.urls')),
]
```

And in my main.urls it doesn't exist any '/' before. How can I troubleshoot where the problem exists? Can I expand the error when I run the dev server with manage.py?

Edit:

This is my main/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from . import views


app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [

    # Create Blog
    url(r'^create-blog/$', views.create_blog, name='create_blog'),

    # Lists
    url(r'^blogs/$', views.blog_list, name='blog_list'),
    url(r'^blogs/new/$', views.blogs_new, name='blogs_new'),
    url(r'^top/$', views.top_lists, name='top_lists'),
    url(r'^latest/$', views.latest_posts, name='latest_posts'),

    # Tags
    url(r'^tags/(?P<tag>[\w-]+)/$', views.tag, name='tag'),
    url(r'^tags/$', views.tags, name='tags'),

    # Avatars
    url(r'^avatar/', include('avatar.urls')),

    # Various
    url(r'^welcome/$', views.welcome, name='welcome'),
    url(r'^faq/$', views.faq, name='faq'),
    url(r'^contact-us/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

Comment: So what does the pattern '^' match? And whatever it matches, how do you ever get to the `mezzanine.urls`?

Comment: You are `+=` adding to urlpatterns, so I guess there is more? Also, post your `main.urls`.

Comment: @C14L Alright, added the main.urls now.

Answer (score 2):

Looking over the question again, perhaps you have literally defined a pattern as `^/` somewhere.

> ?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '^/' has a regex beginning with a '/'. Remove this slash as it is unnecessary.

This [system check](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/checks/#urls) by django is printing out the pattern that is causing problems.  I made a quick django example, and when I put in a url such as...

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^test1/$', views.test1, name='test1'),
    url('^/test2/$', views.test2, name='test2'),
]
```

> ?: (urls.W002) Your URL pattern '^/test2/$' [name='test2'] has a regex beginning with a '/'. Remove this slash as it is unnecessary.

As you can see it is giving me my URL pattern exactly as it is defined, `^/test2/$`. I think your problem is likely in some other part of your **urls.py** file or one of the other **urls.py** files, most likely an include because you do not have the trailing `$` in the pattern nor a name for the view.

Try searching through your project for a url defined as '^/' is my recommendation.

Comment: That's really not what `r` does. It simply prevents Python interpreting backslashes as escape characters.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for that clarification, updated answer should be a bit closer to the mark.